# Can I use my ssh-public-key to decrypt a file?

Tags: ssh-keys, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to find a way to decrypt an encrypted file on a 'virgin' EC2-instance. These EC-instances I use (Ubuntu Lucid) only hold my AWS-created public ssh-key. If can use this to decrypt a file, I can feed it encrypted files (for example a bash-script holding a password to my subversion-repository).

So, my question, can I use my ssh-key to encrypt/decrypt a file?

Comment: A very similar question was asked over at the Unix and Linux StackExchange site. I think there answers there will be of interest: [Encrypting file only with SSH -priv-key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/encrypting-file-only-with-ssh-priv-key).

Comment: Related: [Encrypting file only with SSH -priv-key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27005/21471).

Answer (score 35):

The file:

```
echo 'This is a sekret' >/tmp/msg.txt
```

Export public key (in case you don't have it/lose it):

```
openssl rsa -in ~/private.pem -out /tmp/public.pub -outform PEM -pubout
```

Encrypt file with public key (anyone can have this key):

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey /tmp/public.pub -pubin -in /tmp/msg.txt -out /tmp/file.enc
```

Decrypt the file with private key (only you should have the private key):

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/private.pem -in /tmp/file.enc -out /tmp/decrypted.txt
```

The decoded message:

```
cat /tmp/decrypted.txt
```

Comment: How does this answer address the "ssh" part of the question? I don't see reference here to either "ssh" or files in ".ssh".

Comment: @MarkStosberg, it addresses the problem: "I'm trying to find a way to decrypt an encrypted file on a 'virgin' EC2-instance"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a public key to encrypt a file but you will need the corresponding private key to decrypt it. So, yes, you should be able to use your ssh-key to encrypt/decrypt a file, as long as you have access to both the public and private key.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Can you give an example of the command I have to give (I'm on linux) on how to do this?

sorry, I'm in the dark here...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to encrypt/decrypt using your ssh keys, [ssh-vault](https://ssh-vault.com) could be useful, more info here: http://ssh-vault.com/about/