# How to securly store and use a customer's AWS Secret Key

Tags: security, node.js, amazon-web-services

Is it acceptable to store a customer's secret key & access key id on my server to allow me to access the AWS API on their behalf?

For a password it is simply a matter of using a hash to store an encrypted version but I need to use the actual key value each time I call AWS so I cannot hash it.

In simple terms, for each authenticated user I would store an object a bit like this:

```
{userdId: [myUserId],
 secretKey: 'jHuiU-jiuhd...',
 accessKeyId: 'abcdef...',
 etc}
```

I could then access this each time I call AWS.

Now, I could base64 encode it and / or even encrypt it myself, but at some stage I have to decode and decrypt it to make my request and everything I need to do these options will be stored somewhere on the server.

If the data is kept on the server - never sent back to the client - and if the transport from server to AWS is done over SSL, then is this enough?

Comment: You're talking about a specifically provisioned IAM user access key right? Not the root access keys for the client...

Comment: I guess the ideal keys to use would be ones created via the Security Token Service. One option I was thinking about is to provide a simple interface (from the local client to AWS) to generate a temporary token using a custom policy (for federated access) and then having the client send the server these details.

Answer (score 0):

> How to securly store and use a customer's AWS Secret Key

#### Ansible

If you're using Ansible, consider using [Vault to Protect Sensitive Ansible Data](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data-on-ubuntu-16-04). So you can configure it to encrypt the sensitive contents such as private keys.

#### Keybase

Another way is to use [Keybase](https://keybase.io/) app which provides end-to-end encrypted data across all your devices.

#### PGP

Use [pgp](/questions/tagged/pgp) encryption to encrypt and decrypt sensitive keys.

#### OpenSSL

Use your [public key to encrypt the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811528/55075), then your private keys to decrypt it.

#### SSH Vault

Check `ssh-vault` how it can encrypt/decrypt data using SSH keys.